# Is there any easy/basic way to split a text transcript using R?

Tags: r, transcription

Basically, I have a .txt file of a transcript of a negotiation between two participants with the format:

`Name   Time Stamp   Text    Name   Time Stamp   Text`

and so on and so on for the full conversation. Is there a way to code R to split this transcript into separate variables so that there is a variable for the name, a variable for the time stamp, and a variable for the text for the full transcript?

I've been doing it by hand but as the transcripts get longer and the more there are to do, the harder this is accomplished by hand. I know that there is some code for parsing text to use for sentiment analysis and the like but from what I know of this, I only know how to code to pull out specific parts of speech.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi cwfowler, there is no way we can possibly help you without an accurate, representative sample of the data you are trying to process. Please post a reasonably sized sample of your data.

Comment: Can you `dput` a small sample of the text? I think this may be problematic for a couple of reasons. 1. Many people's names are regular words (Frank, May, June, Bob, Rob, ...). 2. The text may contain the other person's name and/or a timestamp. For example, "May: Yes, Frank. You're correct. That meeting may have been scheduled to start at 1:30pm. But the boss was late. Frankly, he's always late. Maybe we should all quit."

Answer (score 0):

*If I'd realized how hard this was, I'd have skipped this problem.
But I got in a lot of good practice on `pivot_long`*.  `read_csv` will repair those repeated names for you, as will most of the other `read` functions if you give them the right options.

```
library(tidyverse)
Raw <-  readr::read_csv("Name,Time Stamp,Text,Name,Time Stamp,Text,Name,Time Stamp,Text
Arthur,1:22,No,Betty,1:23,Yes,Arthur,1:24,Dang")
# A tibble: 1 x 9
Name   `Time Stamp` Text  Name_1 `Time Stamp_1` Text_1 Name_2 `Time Stamp_2` Text_2
<chr>  <time>       <chr> <chr>  <time>         <chr>  <chr>  <time>         <chr> 
  1 Arthur 01:22        No    Betty  01:23          Yes    Arthur 01:24          Dang
```

Now, let's `pivot_long`:

```
transcript1 <- Raw %>% 
  rowid_to_column("ROW") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Name"), names_to = "Nm", values_to = "NAME") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Time"), names_to = "Ts", values_to = "TIME.STAMP") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Text"), names_to = "Tx", values_to = "TEXT")
```

On ROW =1 We want to associate Nm_2 with Ts_2 with Tx_2 etc.  Let's build a function

```
nmOut <- function(ROW, string){
  ext <- str_extract(string, "(?<=_)\\d+")
  paste(ROW, 
    ifelse(is.na(ext), "0", ext ))
}

transcript2 <- transcript1 %>% 
  mutate(rNm = nmOut(ROW, Nm),
         rTs = nmOut(ROW, Ts),
         rTx = nmOut(ROW, Tx)) %>% 
  filter(rNm == rTs & rTs == rTx)

# A tibble: 3 x 10
    ROW Nm     NAME   Ts           TIME.STAMP Tx     TEXT  rNm   rTs   rTx  
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>        <time>     <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Name   Arthur Time Stamp   01:22      Text   No    1 0   1 0   1 0  
2     1 Name_1 Betty  Time Stamp_1 01:23      Text_1 Yes   1 1   1 1   1 1  
3     1 Name_2 Arthur Time Stamp_2 01:24      Text_2 Dang  1 2   1 2   1 2   




transcriptFinal <- transcript2 %>% 
  select(ROW, NAME, TIME.STAMP, TEXT)

transcriptFinal

# A tibble: 3 x 4
    ROW NAME   TIME.STAMP TEXT 
  <int> <chr>  <time>     <chr>
1     1 Arthur 01:22      No   
2     1 Betty  01:23      Yes  
3     1 Arthur 01:24      Dang
```

Finally, check out Hadley's reference on `pivot_long` : https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#pivoting

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'm sorry it took longer than expected, I should have realized there would be no simple, easy answer for this issue but I appreciate your help!